# Collecting variables from multiple hosts in a playbook

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook that collects a list of information from multiple hosts, and I want to collect those lists together into a single variable.
So for example, my output might look like this:

```
ok: [ALBSWA052] => {
    "myvar": [
        "ALBSWA052 exists",
        "ALBSWA052 is secondary"
    ]
}
ok: [ALBSWA051] => {
    "myvar": [
        "ALBSWA051 exists",
        "ALBSWA051 is primary"
    ]
}
```

and I'd like to combine them into a list like

```
    "myvar": [
        "ALBSWA052 exists",
        "ALBSWA052 is secondary"
        "ALBSWA051 exists",
        "ALBSWA051 is primary"
    ]
```

Is there an elegant way to do this? The only way I can think of is to write it into a file and read it back in.

Comment: Written on spot, untested, just to put you on track to experiment and search the documentation: `{{ hostvars | dict2items | map(attribute='values.myvar' ) | flatten }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        myvar: "{{ ansible_play_hosts|map('extract', hostvars, 'myvar')|flatten }}"
      run_once: true
```

gives the expected result

```yaml
myvar:
  - ALBSWA051 exists
  - ALBSWA051 is secondary
  - ALBSWA052 exists
  - ALBSWA052 is secondary
```

Comment: Addendum: it's necessary to ensure the host-level 'myvar' exists for every host, to prevent problems created by undefined variables.  `set_fact: myvar: []`